# Define AutomaticUnprovisionInterval in the ARM Template correctly

Tags: json, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I need to defing the `AutomaticUnprovisionInterval` parameter in my ARM template. The documentation states that it's a `TimeSpan`, and the default is `Common::TimeSpan::FromMinutes(5)`.

I am trying to figure out how to correctly define that in my template. Anyone has any suggestions or experience doing that?

```json
"AutomaticUnprovisionInterval": {
   "type": "string",
   "defaultValue": ""
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings), it's a timespan in **seconds**.
The `Common::TimeSpan` is a reference to an SF internal [concept](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/blob/92ea1af4fdd6e9b58e137ca28ca8691b5c6c92d6/src/prod/src/Common/TimeSpan.cpp).

Comment: I mean how do I specify the default Value. Do you have an example of doing so?

Comment: "AutomaticUnprovisionInterval": {
   "type": "string",
   "defaultValue": "600"